# Solve the trigonometric equation: $\sin {3x} = 4 \sin^2 x$

Tags: trigonometry

Solve the equation $\sin{3x} = 4 \sin^2 x$.

I tried to change the $\sin{3x}$ to $3\sin x\cos x$ then solve it, but I could not find the correct answer.

Comment: sin(3*x) = 3*cos(x)^2*sin(x) - sin(x)^3, not 3*sin(x)*cos(x).

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** We have $$\sin 3x = 3\sin x - 4\sin^3 x\neq 3\sin x\cos x$$

So you get (let $\sin x = \alpha$) $$3\alpha - 4\alpha^3 = 4\alpha^2 \iff 4\alpha^3 + 4\alpha^2 - 3\alpha = 0$$

Which is a simple cubic in $\alpha$. Find the roots of the cubic, back-substitute and find the corresponding values of $x$.

Comment: a good solution, but please edit your first equation to achieve the perfect answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Hathanhminh. I corrected the typo, thank you! :-)

Comment: Do csc^2 x equal to 1/sin^2 x?

Comment: @user255652 yes.

Answer (score -2):

$\sin(3x)=\sin(2x+x)$
 thus we have:
$$\sin(2x)\cos(x)+\cos(2x)\sin(x)=4\sin^{2}(x)$$
$$2\sin(x)\cos^{2}(x)+(\cos^{2}(x)-\sin^{2}(x))\sin(x)=4\sin^{2}(x)$$
$$\sin(x)(1-\sin^{2}(x))+(1-2\sin^{2}x)\sin(x)=4\sin^{2}(x)$$
$$3\sin(x)-4\sin^{3}(x)=\sin^{2}(x)$$
$$3\sin(x)-4\sin^{3}(x)=\sin^{2}(x)$$
$$3\sin(x)-4\sin^{3}(x)-\sin^{2}(x)=0$$
$$\sin(x)(3-4\sin^{2}(x)-\sin^{2}(x))=0$$

Simply assign $\sin x=a$ then you get $a=6/8$ and $-9/8$ and $a=0$
$x=\sin^{-1}(6/8)$ or $\sin^{-1}(-9/8)$ or $sin^{-}(0)$

Comment: Here is my answer and there are no explanations, if you don't understand or you like to be explained clearer I am here to help!

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference and +1

Comment: It's a cubic, not a quadratic.

Comment: @ZainPatel yes a third solution also appears a=0, I will insert in the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Notice, $$\sin 3x=4\sin^2 x$$ $$\implies 3\sin x-4\sin^3x=4\sin^2 x$$ $$\implies 4\sin^3x+4\sin^2 x-3\sin x=0$$$$\implies \sin x(4\sin^2x+4\sin x-3)=0$$
$$\implies \sin x(2\sin x-1)(2\sin x+3)=0$$ As you have not mentioned any condition of the unknown value $x$ hence writing the general solution for $x$ as follows $$\implies \color{blue}{\sin x=0}\iff \color{blue}{x=n\pi} $$  $$\implies \color{blue}{2\sin x-1=0\ \text{or}\ \sin x=\frac{1}{2}\ or \ \sin x=\sin\frac{\pi}{6}}\iff \color{blue}{x=2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{6}} $$
$$or\ \color{blue}{\sin x=\sin\frac{5\pi}{6}}\iff \color{blue}{x=2n\pi+\frac{5\pi}{6}} $$

$$\implies \color{blue}{2\sin x+3=0\ \text{or}\ \sin x=\frac{-3}{2}}\iff \color{blue}{\sin x\neq \frac{-3}{2}} $$  Now, the complete general solution can be written as $$\color{blue}{x=[n\pi]\cup\left[2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{6}\right]\cup\left[2n\pi+\frac{5\pi}{6}\right]}$$
Where $\color{blue}{\text{n is any integer}}$

Comment: How is sin(3x) equal to 4sin^{2}(x)?

Comment: Kindly, notice $\sin 3x=3\sin x-4\sin^3 x$ it is not equal to $4\sin^2 x$ as you asked

Comment: More over a you have not mentioned any condition of the unknown value $x$ therefore I gave general solution that's it. Kindly observe all the steps carefully then you may find the solution

Comment: Sorry, I asked you the question, what am I thinking, yes you gave the general solution.